# Straight line touching two circles - fixed to another straight line

Tags: geometry

I want to find a series of steps or equations, that if possible can be put into a spreadsheet to solve the general case of the following problem.  A straight line length $(a+b)$ touches two circles, radius $r_1$ centre $(x_1,y_1)$ and radius $r_2$ centre $(x_2,y_2)$. The point $O$ of this line is fixed to another straight line equation $y=mx+c$ such that length from this line to the first circle is always $a$ and from this line to the second circle is always $b$.
[image]
I wish to get the coordinates $(x_a, y_a)$ and $(x_b, y_b)$ at where the line touches each circle and also $(x_O,y_O)$ at where it intersects $y=mx+c$. 
So far I have only managed to get answers by trial and error and not by drawing or mathematical calculation. The smaller circle is not always inside the larger circle.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58UuD.jpg)

Comment: Please attach a better image. The black background makes it almost impossible (for my old eyes) to decipher it.

Comment: are the circle centers fixed? You have a four bar linkeage with a constraint that point _O_ lies on a line. So the configuration is fully constrained with no degrees of freedom. Is this correct?

Comment: What is the interest of the line $y=mx+n$ and in particular the interest to have it described in this way (meaning of $m$ and $n$ ?). For me, it plays no role because it does not provide any new constraint on the problem. Am I right ?

Comment: Thankyou all.  I have added a clearer image now.

Comment: As drawn all parts are fixed.  I need to do the calculation for the parts being in given fixed positions. (Known x1, y1, x2, y2, r1, r2, m, c, a and b).  The parts drawn are moving parts and may be of different sizes hence the need for a general calculation.

Comment: The line y=mx+c constrains the line I want to find the coordinates of, such that the distance from that line to one circle is always a, and to the other circle is always b.  (Without that constraint there are many possible locations for the line!)

Comment: It is clear that the probability to get a solution is low since "a" is limited in length and same with "b". Suggest to start with finding a solution for "a" only and than check if "b" is satisfied.

Comment: I suggest two steps: first find the limits based on "a" and "b" if a solution is possible - this step is straight forward. The second step - if there is a possible solution - to find it seems to be challenging.

Comment: Using theory: by finding the line equation that contains "a" and "b" get two equations based on the three intersections. This seems to be quite involved.